# Updating set outside of function scope

Tags: r, set

I am trying to add genres to my `genres` set. However, I am getting `NULL` for my genres set.

function:

```
install.packages("sets"); library(sets)
genres = set()
find_all_genres = function(genres_string) {
  if (genres_string == "N/A") {
    return(NA)
  }
  genres_list = strsplit(genres_string, ",\\s+")[[1]]
  for (genre in genres_list) {
    genres = genres | set(genre)
  }
}

sapply(df2$Genre, FUN = find_all_genres)
```

Sample:

```
> head(df2$Genre)
[1] "Documentary, Biography, Romance" "Short, Thriller"                 "Documentary"                     "Drama, Romance"                  "War, Short"                     
[6] "Documentary, Biography"
```

The expected output would be something alone the lines of:

```
genres = {"Action", "Drama", "Comedy"}
```

With of course many more genres.

Also, how can I speed up my function? I am new to R

Comment: @G.Grothendieck updated. I was surprised R did not some with a built-in set library

Comment: @G.Grothendieck done

Answer (score 1):

Use `scan` to read it in and `unique` to remove duplicates.  `g` is given in the Note at the end. No packages are used.

```
unique(scan(text = g, what = "", sep = ",", na.strings = "N/A", 
  strip.white = TRUE, quiet = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
[1] "Documentary" "Biography"   "Romance"     "Short"       "Thriller"   
[6] "Drama"       "War"
```

Use `sort` afterwards if you want it sorted.

### Function

If you want to add to some previous values writing the entire thing as a function:

```
add <- function(...) {
    unique(scan(text = c(...), what = "", sep = ",", na.strings = "N/A", 
      strip.white = TRUE, quiet = TRUE))
}

# examples
g_split <- add(g)

G <- c("Drama", "Comedy")
G <- add(G, g)
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
g <- c("Documentary, Biography, Romance", "Short, Thriller", "Documentary", 
  "Drama, Romance", "War, Short", "Documentary, Biography")
```